# Toggle one component from another using React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, toggle

I have a two child components and I want a button in one of them to toggle (on/off) the html in another. I have watched tutorials on lifting state up, and communication between components but most of it has to do with moving data. I want to manipulate a component from another. I would like the achieve this using useState, and without useContext if possible. Thanks!

THE PARENT

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppProvider>
        <ComponentOne/>
        <Slideshow />
        <ComponentTwo/ >
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );

}
```

CHILD 1

```
export default function ComponentOne() {
 

  return (
    <div>
      <button>The button that toggles</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CHILD 2

```
export default function ComponentTwo() {
 

  return (
    <div>
      <div>The content that hides/shows</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `state` to toggle the values. Pass the state to the `ComponentTwo` as props and pass the state updater function as the callback function to the `ComponentOne` as a prop.

```
import React , { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function ComponentOne({ onToggle}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onToggle}>The button that toggles</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentTwo({show}) {

  return (
    <div>
     {show && <div>The content that hides/shows</div>} 
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow ] = useState(true);

  const handleToggle = useCallback(() => setShow(prevShow => !prevShow),[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentOne onToggle={handleToggle} />
      <ComponentTwo show={show} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Refer**

[useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: Thank you, this answers it! Can i ask why you have useCallback? I am unfamiliar with that hook. Is there an alternative way without useCallback using only useState? and if so, why not  just do that?

Comment: The reason to use , useCallback here is everytime when there is a state change you re-run the function `App` due to this you will be creating the `handleToggle` function each time and passing at as props to the `ComponentOne` . Now consider `ComponentOne` renders a table along with the button. Now because the reference of handleToggle changes each time the component will keep re-rendering which results in re-rendering the table each time . But your intention is to only re-render ComponentTwo.